# Existence of extremal value

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima, extreme-value-analysis

Determine the minimum and maximum values of the function $\frac{x^4}{(x-1)(x-3)^3}$.
By equating the first derivative to $0$,its fairly simple to deduce that the extreme points are $x=0,\frac{6}{5}$. However,to determine minimum or maxumum,we need to analyse the 2nd derivative as well which seems to be awfully long. Is there any way to do it simply?

Comment: You could try analysing the first derivative and think: if I add an number infinitely small, what will happen will the value of the first derivative go up or down

Answer (score 1):

Call your function $f$. Notice that the numerator is always non-negative. Now, in some neighbourhood of $0$ we have $x-1<0$ and $x-3<0$, so the denominator is always non-negative in that neighbourhood. As $f(0)=0$, it must be a minimum.

As the only roots of $f'$ are $0$ and $\dfrac{6}{5}$ and it is a continuous function, it must have a constant sign on $\left(1,\dfrac{6}{5}\right)$ and a constant sign on $\left(\dfrac{6}{5},3\right)$. Evaluating, one gets that $f'\left(\dfrac{11}{10}\right)>0$ and $f'(2)<0$ , so $f$ increases on $\left(1,\dfrac{6}{5}\right)$ and decreases on $\left(\dfrac{6}{5},3\right)$, from where $f$ attains a maximum at $\dfrac{6}{5}$.

Comment: The 2nd derivative turns out to be $2\times \frac{(x-1)^2(x-3)^4(18x^2-20x^3)-2(6x^3-5x^4)(x-1)(x-3)^3(3x-5)}{(x-1)^4(x-3)^8}$. Here 0 satisfies that the 2nd derivative is 0,so 0 should neither be maximum or minimum.

Comment: @a_i_r The fact that $f''(0)=0$ does not mean $0$ isn't a maximum or a minimum; $f(x)=x^4$ serves as a counterexample.

Comment: Isn't the condition for maxima $f''(x)<0$ and for minima $f''(x)>0$? This is the theory I learnt about local extrema all this time.

Comment: That is a sufficient condition, **not** a necessary one

Comment: Desmos shows that in the neighbourhood of $0$,there are a lot of other points which also give the value $0$,could you please check where is the mistake?Since only 2 extreme points have been found.

Comment: There is no mistake. I don't know what other $0$'s you are talking about.

Comment: I meant plugging $x=0$ in the original function,we get $f(x)=0$ but according to desmos,there are such $x$ not equal to $0$ for which $f(x)=0$. In that case,why weren't those non zero values be derived using first derivative test?

Comment: The only point such that $f(x)=0$ is $x=0$, because a fraction is $0$ iff the numerator is $0$. The fact that a graphing calculator shows values close to zero doesn't mean those are actually roots.

Answer (score 0):

The function tends to $1$ at $-\infty$ and to $\infty$ when $x\to 1^-.$ As $0$ is the only stationary point in $(-\infty,1),$ it must be a minimum. On the other hand $6/5$ belongs to the interval, where the function tends to $-\infty$ at $1^+$ and at $3^-.$ Therefore the function attains a maximum at $6/5
$

Comment: Please check my comment to the other answer kindly.

Comment: I don't get your point. No second derivative is used in my answer

Comment: I meant as in your solution,$0$ should be a minimum but 2nd derivative(which I calculated) shows $f"(0)=0$,which implies $0$ is neither minimum nor maxima since for maxima we need $f"(x)<0$ and for minima $f"(x)>0$.

Comment: The second derivative test may be inconclusive. For example $f(x)=x^4$ at $0.$ The better test is to study the signs of the first derivative on both sides of the stationary point.